# ClickHouse SELECT returning empty rows. Query is correct and works on ClickHouse SQL Console

Tags: sql, go, clickhouse

So I'm using a ClickHouse DB and trying to run the following query in a Go API.

```
SELECT (SELECT  round(sum(a.amount),2) FROM activity a WHERE a.created_at >= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.created_at <= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.account_id = ? AND a.funnel_id= ? AND a.event_id=2) AS value, (SELECT  round(sum(a.amount),2) FROM activity a WHERE a.created_at >= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.created_at <= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.account_id = ? AND a.funnel_id= ? AND a.event_id=2) AS old_value;
```

The query values are inserted when the query is ran using the ClickHouse library.

The issue is this query should work and returns row {Value: 360, oldValue: 360} in the ClickHouse SQL console which is the expected result. But when running in the Go API I get no rows returned which is seen when I call `defer rows.Close()` and then when trying to read any rows I get the following error: `2023/08/21 08:58:54 sql: Rows are closed`

All connection details are correct and connection is OK as ping works so I have no idea what is wrong. Any help appreciated. Full console output and code below.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/v2"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var conn *sql.DB = nil

type Summary struct {
    value    float64
    oldValue float64
}

func main() {
    Setup()
    s_time := 1691654400
    e_time := 1691686800
    acc_id := 14612
    fun_id := 7267

    values := []interface{}{s_time, e_time, acc_id, fun_id, s_time, e_time, acc_id, fun_id}
    query := "SELECT (SELECT  round(sum(a.amount),2) FROM activity a WHERE a.created_at >= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.created_at <= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.account_id = ? AND a.funnel_id= ? AND a.event_id=2) AS value, (SELECT  round(sum(a.amount),2) FROM activity a WHERE a.created_at >= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.created_at <= FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND a.account_id = ? AND a.funnel_id= ? AND a.event_id=2) AS old_value;"

    ExecuteQuery(query, values)
}

func Setup() {
    godotenv.Load()
    conn = clickhouse.OpenDB(&clickhouse.Options{
        Addr: []string{os.Getenv("CLICKHOUSE_CONNECTION_STRING")},
        Auth: clickhouse.Auth{
            Database: os.Getenv("CLICKHOUSE_DBNAME"),
            Username: os.Getenv("CLICKHOUSE_USER"),
            Password: os.Getenv("CLICKHOUSE_PASS"),
        },
        TLS: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: false,
        },
        Settings: clickhouse.Settings{
            "max_execution_time": 60,
        },
        Debug:                true,
        BlockBufferSize:      10,
        MaxCompressionBuffer: 10240,
        Protocol:             clickhouse.HTTP,
    })

    conn.SetMaxIdleConns(5)
    conn.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
    conn.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)

    err := conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Ping failed on ClickHouse DB")
    } else {
        log.Println("ClickHouse DB Live :)")
    }
}

func ExecuteQuery(query string, values []interface{}) {
    rows := conn.QueryRow(query, values...)
    sum := Summary{}

    if err := rows.Scan(&sum.value, &sum.oldValue); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(sum.value)
    fmt.Println(sum.oldValue)
}
```

```
2023/08/21 09:52:42 ClickHouse DB Live :)
2023/08/21 09:52:42 sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "value": converting driver.Value type *float64 ("0xc000090128") to a float64: invalid syntax
0
0
```

Comment: A deferred function call is executed when the surrounding function exits. This means that when `ExecuteQuery` exits, the returned rows will be closed and you will not be able to scan anything anymore.

Comment: Note also that, to scan data from a `*sql.Rows` object you MUST first call `rows.Next()` before each scan. This is usually done in the `for` statement, like so: `for rows.Next() { ... scan logic ... }`. (see the example here: https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.21.0#DB.Query). If you want just a single row you should use `QueryRow` instead of `Query`.

Comment: @mkopriva ok so I changed my ExecuteQuery code to scan the result there and use QueryRow and still get 0's instead of my expected result.  I checked my query_log on ClickHouse and it the value is secure is set to 0 not 1, is this an issue?

Comment: Hard to say what the issue could be without seeing the updated code. I'd also recommend to test the connection with a more simple query, for example `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity`, and then compare the result of that against the result from the same query but executed in the console, because it could be that your Go program connects to a separate database than your console (or a different schema, but I don't know if that's even a thing in clickhouse).

Comment: Updated code added, i've tried with simple queries and had the same issue of blank rows on return. Speaking to CH support but they are SO slow.

Comment: Note that in the updated error message the problem is not that the query isn't returning any rows, but that the returned `value` column's value cannot be converted to `float64`.

Comment: I'm not sure why because return value is float64 in CH SQL console and in the struct i'm trying to scan to. Is there a way to scan into a dynamically allocated variable?

Comment: Fixed the issue finally, it returns pointers and then have to read the pointers separately.... Thanks for the help